# Running Python script from bash: Command not found error

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I Get command not found error. 0 and $filestem are the two args and I had the following in a script. And when i execute the script, I get command not found.

```
echo -e "Enter the file stem name"
read filestem
python gen_par_final.py 0 $filestem
```

The input files, the python script and the bash script are all in the same folder. the python script works at the command promt as such but  not inside the script. Is there any path to be set or something that will resolve the problem?

Comment: should it not be `read $filestem` ?

Comment: If you modify the code above to take no arguments then do you get the same error?  Just trying to see if your python script it broken or the way you handle arguments.

Comment: I did remove the args and ran the code. It still gives me error.

Comment: What is the output of `which python`?  Is `python` an alias?

Comment: which python gives /usr/bin/Python and python is alias

Comment: I have found that aliases aren't always found in a shell script.  Try using `/usr/bin/Python` and see if that works in your script.  You might want to figure out why python was installed with a capital letter.

Comment: Maybe a permissions issue? What "command" isn't found exactly?

Comment: @Vignesh since after removing the arguments and you still get that error then it has to do with just the call to `python`.

Comment: @Andenthal I use a variable big in the python script. the error is "Big command not found". whioch is so weird. how can the variable be assumed as a command?

Answer (score 5):

This could work

1. Insert this `#! /usr/bin/Python` at the top of `gen_par_final.py` file.

   (It's usually `/usr/bin/python` you need to check out how it's capital `P`)
2. Make `gen_par_final.py` executable.
   `$ chmod +x gen_par_final.py`
3. Edit your shell script.

   `echo -e "Enter the file stem name"`
    `read filestem`
    `./gen_par_final.py 0 $filestem`

Comment: I tried this. while executing it gives me a area selection type cursor and this error import: unable to grab mouse `': Resource temporarily unavailable @ xwindow.c/XSelectWindow/8969.

Comment: Check if this works on terminal `$ ./gen_par_final.py 0 <sample_arg>`.

Comment: Isn't it normally `#!/usr/bin/python` ? There's no space and the P is lowercase. Also, you said "usually". So, to make it platform independent you could use `#!/usr/bin/env python` so the $PATH will return the python default, regardless of where it's located on the system.

Comment: this answer could be improved by also explained why the proposed solution would work

Answer (score 0):

could `/path/to/python ./gen_par_final.py 0 ${filestem}` solve this?

I assume you checked for spelling errors?